# Add flag to html_entity_decode in array_map

Tags: php, array-map

This works fine...

```
$row = array_map("html_entity_decode", $row);
```

BUT, I need to add the ENT_QUOTES flag and I cannot get it to work. Any ideas?

```
$row = array_map("html_entity_decode, ENT_QUOTES", $row);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a lambda function notation like this (PHP 7.4+)

```
$row = array_map(fn($e) => html_entity_decode($e, ENT_QUOTES), $row);
```

Before PHP 7.4 just use the normal anonymous function

```
$row = array_map(function($e) { return html_entity_decode($e, ENT_QUOTES); }, $row);
```

Comment: Any solution for 5.6?

Comment: @ScottWeisberg For sure, just the old notation. Answer updated.

Comment: The solution for PHP5.6 = upgrade to a supported php version.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Please help us to close duplicate questions.

Comment: PHP's array_map() supports a third parameter which is an array representing the parameters to pass to the callback function.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do it...

```
    function myFunc($a) {
    return html_entity_decode($a, ENT_QUOTES);
    }

    $row = array_map("myFunc", $row);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try with array_walk_recursive

```
array_walk_recursive($yourArray, function (&$value) { $value = html_entity_decode($value, ENT_QUOTES); });
```